# Fancybox script not working when there are many forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

I have a lot of forms:

```
<?php
    foreach ($listaMaterial as $id) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $id[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . $id[1] . "</td>
            <td>" . $id[2] . "</td>
            <td>" . $id[3] . "</td>
            <td>" . $id[4] ." </td>
            <td><form method=post action=../popup.php class=rub id=rub>
            <input type='hidden' name='codigo' id='rub1' value=".$id[0].">
            <input type='submit' value='send' class='send'></form></td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
?>
```

php code like

```
<form method=post action=../popup.php class=rub id=rub">
<input type='hidden' name='codigo' id='rub1' value="17">
<input type='submit' value='send' class='send'></form>

<form method=post action=../popup.php class=rub id=rub>
<input type='hidden' name='codigo' id='rub1' value="18">
<input type='submit' value='send' class='send'></form>
...
...
...
```

Upon the click of this submit I'd like the form submit data to be transferred to  Fancybox. using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".rub").submit(function() {

   $form = $(this);

$.ajax({
url: $form.attr("action"),
type: 'POST',
data: $form.serialize(),
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
$(".rub").fancybox({
    width       : '600',
    height      : '450',
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    'content': data
});
}
});

return false;

});
});

</script>
```

it is working but same window !!!!
have to be different datas.
and also using fancybox ajax very slow!!w!!
Using the method suggested in the thread above, what exactly is the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `success` argument like this

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
 $.fancybox(data,{
    width       : 600,
    height      : 450,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'elastic'
 });
}
```

because `$(".rub").fancybox()` only binds (on success) fancybox to the selector `.rub`, but it doesn't execute it. Also, integer and Boolean values go without quotes.